# Mass Push notification gets my server down

Tags: ios, notifications, push

When I send mass push notification  to my iOS app users (around 100,000), after my PHP page says "Done: messages has ben sent to X users), my server goes down and shutdown, although the page is done of sending, and all users got my message.

Why my server goes down? I only send request to Apple Gateway Server and their server does the hard job.

My script:

```
$sound = "default"; 
$passphrase = 'pass';
$message = 'some message';

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => $sound,
    'badge' => 1
    );

$payload = '{"aps":{"alert":"' . $message . '","sound":"' . $sound  . '","badge":1}}';

$results = mysql_query ("Select * from tokens");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
  $deviceToken = $row[Token];
  $i ++;

  $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
  $result = fwrite($fp, $msg,strlen($msg));  

  if (!$result) {
    fclose($fp);
    sleep (3);
    $fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
    if (!$fp) exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
  }

}


fclose($fp);
echo "Done: messages has ben sent to $i users.";

}
```

I have VPS with 2GB RAM.

Any ideas what's causing this issue, and a way to avoid it?

Comment: instead of sending 100,000 at one moment. Send the 100,000 over the course of 15 minutes instead of all at once. you may be maxing out the number of connection nodes. You may even want to spread it out over 30 minutes to be safe. Try doing 2000 per minute or various intervals, and see if it improves performance.

Comment: remember since SSL is secure, the cost is much much much higher than unsecured channels.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Did you find out how to send it to 2000 per minute? Could you post the solution you ended up using?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not the fact that the push notification is sent from your server, but the users who **click on the notification** immediately when it arrives **produce load** for your server.

I had the same problem and solved it in such a way that I do not send topic messages or messages to all users at once, but instead **send out messages in small chunks** to users. A delay between the chunks should be adjusted to the capacity of the server.